# Columns name of SMS Cursor?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 lines code:

```
private static final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"); 
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);
```

Where to find column list of this cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using below code

```
String[] list = cursor.getColumnNames();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes :)

```
private static final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);
android.util.Log.i("COLUMNS", Arrays.toString(c.getColumnNames()));
```

And the answer is:

```
05-27 09:27:39: INFO/COLUMNS: [_id, thread_id, address, person, date, protocol,
read, status, type, reply_path_present, subject, body, service_center, locked]
```

This, BTW, is the exact table structure of table SMS in MMSSMS database - connect DDMS to the emulator and use FileExplorer to get the whole database from:

```
data/data/com.android.provider.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

Then use SQLite Database Browser (free) to take a look at the tables. Be sure to simulate one SMS from DDMS so that there is something in the tables, though :)